# Getting Zend_Http Final URL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-http-client

Making a simple request like:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://example.org');
$response = $client->request();
```

How can I get the final URL after the redirects?
I have not seen a way in the documentation or the API docs unless I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Http_Client update the last URL into Zend_Http_Client->uri property if there is redirect.

```
$sourceUrl = 'http://google.com';
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($sourceUrl); 
$response = $client->request(); 
$finalUrl = $client->getUri()->__toString();

var_dump($sourceUrl);
// string(17) "http://google.com"
var_dump($finalUrl);
// string(25) "http://www.google.com:80/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested :

```
$response->getHeader('Location');
```

Comment: Location is contained in the header when there is a redirect. The header does not contain the final URL. I have given up and started to use curl. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Get the last request from the client and then extract the headers.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://webonyx.com');
$response = $client->request();
$lastHeaders = Zend_Http_Response::extractHeaders($client->getLastRequest());

// $lastHeaders['host'] will be your final redirected host
```